# Gradinet not applying in kitkat devices android

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat

I have applied gradient to the activity_main.xml, when i run on marshmallow device gradient is applied, but when i run on kitkat device gradient is not applied. Here is the activity_main.xml look likes

**Marshmallow UI screen:**

[image]

**Kitkat UI screen:**

[image]

Here is the activity_main.xml source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the gradient code i'm using

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#295e7c"
    android:centerY="0"
    android:endColor="#303a70"
    android:gradientRadius="775dp"
    android:startColor="#56a68d"
    android:type="radial" />
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the code as you said and it is working good for both kitkat and marshmallow version's. There is a problem, if you are using multiple layouts then you call this method in those classes.

```
ssv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ssv);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
    new int[]{0xFF56a68d, 0xFF295e7c, 0xFF303a70});
    gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(0f);
    gradientDrawable.setGradientRadius(775f);
    gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(0.5f, 0);
    gradientDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
    ssv.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `dp` from `gradientRadius`

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#295e7c"
    android:centerY="0"
    android:endColor="#303a70"
    android:gradientRadius="775"
    android:startColor="#56a68d"
    android:type="radial" />
```

Comment: @Karthik Donot remove gradientRadius. Only change value from 775dp to only 775. Remove dp only.

Comment: yeah, i have changed the code as you said, i worked fine in kitkat device, but in marshallow device it was not good looking.

Comment: The value 775 needs to be adjusted for your requirement.